# Every time I try to deploy I get - (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm new to Google cloud and I'm trying to do my first deploy to it. My first deploy is a Ruby on Rails project.

I'm basically following [this guide in the google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world). The only difference being that I'm using my own project instead of the 'hello world' project they supply.

This is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: custom
vm: true
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup -p 8080 -E production config.ru
resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

When I go to my project directory and run `gcloud preview app deploy` it starts the deploy but appears to eventually time out. It gives the error  `(gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`.

Doing some research I found running `gcloud preview app deploy` with `--verbosity debug` gives extra debug info but it doesn't help me find whats causing it to timeout.

Here is the last chunk of the console log.

```
Bundle complete! 35 Gemfile dependencies, 102 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
Post-install message from compass:
    Compass is charityware. If you love it, please donate on our behalf at http://umdf.org/compass Thanks!
DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/guidir-1286/MmFkZjNmOGYtZDhhZi00NTJmLTk0YWEtMmQzMjBmM2JkOTg2OlVT] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOperationMetadata", 
        "build": {
            "finishTime": "2016-04-20T01:55:44.961635Z", 
            "status": "TIMEOUT", 
            "timeout": "600.000s", 
            "projectId": "guidir-1286", 
            "id": "2adf3f8f-d8af-452f-94aa-2d320f3bd986", 
            "source": {
                "storageSource": {
                    "object": "us.gcr.io/guidir-1286/appengine/default.20160420t110030:latest", 
                    "bucket": "staging.guidir-1286.appspot.com"
                }
            }, 
            "steps": [
                {
                    "args": [
                        "us.gcr.io/guidir-1286/appengine/default.20160420t110030:latest"
                    ], 
                    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dockerizer"
                }
            ], 
            "startTime": "2016-04-20T01:45:43.216420Z", 
            "logsBucket": "staging.guidir-1286.appspot.com", 
            "images": [
                "us.gcr.io/guidir-1286/appengine/default.20160420t110030:latest"
            ], 
            "createTime": "2016-04-20T01:45:41.861657Z"
        }
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "operations/build/guidir-1286/MmFkZjNmOGYtZDhhZi00NTJmLTk0YWEtMmQzMjBmM2JkOTg2OlVT", 
    "error": {
        "message": "DEADLINE_EXCEEDED", 
        "code": 4
    }
}
DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 654, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1401, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/preview/app/deploy.py", line 507, in Run
    config_cleanup)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 195, in BuildAndPushDockerImages
    storage_client)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 245, in _BuildImagesWithCloudBuild
    image.tag, cloudbuild_client)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/cloud_build.py", line 181, in ExecuteCloudBuild
    retry_callback=log_tailer.Poll)
  File "/Users/Robert/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/api/operations.py", line 69, in WaitForOperation
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(completed_operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
```

This is the furthest its gone, but sometimes its mid way through installing the gems before it times out and other times it doesn't even get upto installing the gems.

How can I stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a 10 minute default timeout for Docker builds (the mechanism by which `runtime: custom` App Engine builds work). You can increase this by running `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout [NUMBER OF SECONDS]`.

You could also work around by performing the build yourself:

```
docker build . -t gcr.io/myapp/myimage
gcloud docker push gcr.io/myapp/myimage
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --image-url=gcr.io/myapp/myimage
```

However, in general, your Docker builds shouldn't be taking this long. It's usually better to have a base image with all of your dependencies already built in, and just have the final build derive from that image and install your app. This way, your builds will be much quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the help I not get the error `Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details` when I run `gcloud preview app modules get-logs mymodule --version=1` to get the logs I cant find where the log file is saved to. Do you know where it would be?

Comment: `gcloud docker` should be replaced by `gcloud auth configure-docker
docker push` since 18.03 docker version

`WARNING: 'gcloud docker' will not be supported for Docker client versions above 18.03.`

Answer (score 11):

This error is raised when the overall request times out.

The execution limit is 10 minutes for task queue requests.
You can increase this timeout limit on google cloud shell, by typing `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout [TIMEOUT_SECONDS]`

Example

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1000
```